# Error when trying to install Lubuntu over Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to install Lubuntu to replace Ubuntu, when executing the command on terminal it gives an error (below), please can someone shed a light?
Many thanks

```
fd@fd-lenovo:~$ sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
[sudo] password for fd: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed
 lubuntu-desktop : Depends: lxqt-core but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: hplip but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to **add** Lubuntu's **desktop environment** (that is, LXDE) to the regular Ubuntu installation rather than - as you describe - "install Lubuntu to replace Ubuntu". Is this what you actually want? I don't know if this is possible, as your message says that there are incompatible versions of packages in both desktop environments (ie. the one currently installed and the one you are trying to install).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `apt policy lubuntu-desktop`